# Cutting ListView off at the bottom of the screen

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

In a flutter app I have a widget structure like the following:

```
Container(
  height: variable,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...,
      ListView(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

How can I set the height of the last ListView so that it takes up exactly the remaining space of the outer Container?
The remaining height for the inner ListView is variable as well, as the ListView is positioned inside another ListView, which can be in different scroll positions.

The screen looks like this:
[image]

The ListView mentioned is the last one you see at the bottom. The problem is, that as its size is to big it actually continues offscreen, making it impossible to scroll through the whole list from this scrolling position of the outer ListView. How can I change that (clip the inner ListView at the end of the screen)?
The code is:

```
SnappingSheet(
            // fixed part of sheet (dragable on this widget)
            grabbingHeight: 90,
            grabbing: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: theme.backgroundColor,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // drag indicator bar
                  Container(
                    width: 30.0,
                    height: 5.0,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8.8,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: theme.hintColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          2.5,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // search field
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 4.0,
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: theme.hintColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: 'search for city/item/shop/category',
                          // TODO: turn into flexible icon to delete text
                          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // dynamic part of sheet (scrollable)
            sheetBelow: Container(
              color: theme.backgroundColor,
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10.0,
                ),
                children: <Widget>[
                  // label for recommended items
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 18.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Recommended items',
                      style: theme.textTheme.headline6,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // recommended items list view
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 10.0,
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0,
                      ),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: globals.searchReturn.recommendedItems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final ItemResult recommendedItem =
                            globals.searchReturn.recommendedItems[index];
                        // TODO: make card selectable
                        // recommended item card
                        return Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          color: theme.accentColor,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              // recommended item image
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 4.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 4.0),
                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  child: Builder(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      try {
                                        return Image.network(
                                          recommendedItem.imageUrl,
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        );
                                      } catch (_) {
                                        return Image.asset(
                                          'assets/placeholder_image.png',
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // recommended item label
                              Positioned(
                                left: 5.0,
                                right: 5.0,
                                top: 107.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100.0,
                                  child: Text(
                                    recommendedItem.name,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // button to switch to info page (for item)
                              Positioned(
                                right: 2.0,
                                top: 2.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  child: CupertinoButton(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.info_outline,
                                      color: theme.hintColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  // label for recommended shops
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 18.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Recommended shops',
                      style: theme.textTheme.headline6,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // recommended shops list view
                  Container(
                    height: 150.0,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 10.0,
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0,
                      ),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: globals.searchReturn.recommendedShops.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final ShopResult recommendedShop =
                            globals.searchReturn.recommendedShops[index];
                        // TODO: make card selectable
                        // recommended shop card
                        return Card(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          color: theme.accentColor,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              // recommended shop image
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      blurRadius: 4.0,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 4.0),
                                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  child: Builder(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      try {
                                        return Image.network(
                                          recommendedShop.imageUrl,
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        );
                                      } catch (_) {
                                        return Image.asset(
                                          'assets/placeholder_image.png',
                                          height: 100.0,
                                          width: 100.0,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        );
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // reccomended shop label
                              Positioned(
                                left: 5.0,
                                right: 5.0,
                                top: 107.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 100.0,
                                  child: Text(
                                    recommendedShop.name,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              // button to switch to info page (for shop)
                              Positioned(
                                right: 2.0,
                                top: 2.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 25.0,
                                  width: 25.0,
                                  child: CupertinoButton(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.info_outline,
                                      color: theme.hintColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  // search results label
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 18.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Search results',
                      style: theme.textTheme.headline6,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // search results list
                  Container(
                    // TODO: find right height
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 522.0,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 10.0),
                      itemCount: globals.searchReturn.otherResults.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final SearchResult searchResult =
                            globals.searchReturn.otherResults[index];
                        // TODO: make card selectable
                        // Card for a search result
                        return Container(
                          height: 60.0,
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            color: theme.accentColor,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                // search result image
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        blurRadius: 4.0,
                                        offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    child: Builder(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        try {
                                          return Image.network(
                                            searchResult.imageUrl,
                                            height: 60.0,
                                            width: 60.0,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          );
                                        } catch (_) {
                                          return Image.asset(
                                            'assets/placeholder_image.png',
                                            height: 100.0,
                                            width: 100.0,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // search result name (title)
                                Positioned(
                                  left: 69.0,
                                  right: 45.0,
                                  top: 4.0,
                                  child: Text(
                                    searchResult.name,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: theme.textTheme.subtitle2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // search result address (subtitle)
                                Positioned(
                                  left: 70.0,
                                  right: 45.0,
                                  top: 22.0,
                                  child: Text(
                                    searchResult.address,
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // button to switch to info page
                                Positioned(
                                  top: 0.0,
                                  bottom: 0.0,
                                  right: 0.0,
                                  child: CupertinoButton(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.info_outline,
                                      color: theme.hintColor,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            snapPositions: <SnapPosition>[
              SnapPosition(
                positionFactor: 0.0,
              ),
              SnapPosition(
                positionFactor: 0.5,
              ),
              SnapPosition(
                positionPixelFromTop: 30.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Can you share a working code example of your issue? Also images of the screen would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

What I suggest you is this, if I understand what you're trying to achieve

`Container(
  height: variable,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ...,
      Expanded(
        child : ListView(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),`

Comment: But the outer list needs to be scrollable as well

Comment: I need the code of this part of your app. Forget about the map. Just the part at the bottom